# Function over react class how it's executed?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm react newb. Trying to learn react-firebase tutorial from this link: https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial/ and can't able to get what is going on with some function and class.

Here is code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import { firebase } from '../firebase';

const withAuthentication = (Component) => {
  class WithAuthentication extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      const { onSetAuthUser } = this.props;

      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        authUser
          ? onSetAuthUser(authUser)
          : onSetAuthUser(null);
      });
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <Component />
      );
    }
  }

  const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    onSetAuthUser: (authUser) => dispatch({ type: 'AUTH_USER_SET', authUser }),
  });

  return connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(WithAuthentication);
}

export default withAuthentication;
```

I know much of the things from this code but initially the function is created and then class with same name is created. What's magic going over here. And other thing is that in outside function argument is given as Component, why is it so!?

Here is other code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { compose } from 'recompose';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

import { firebase } from '../firebase';
import * as routes from '../constants/routes';

const withAuthorization = (condition) => (Component) => {
  class WithAuthorization extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
      firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged(authUser => {
        if (!condition(authUser)) {
          this.props.history.push(routes.SIGN_IN);
        }
      });
    }

    render() {
      return this.props.authUser ? <Component /> : null;
    }
  }

  const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    authUser: state.sessionState.authUser,
  });

  return compose(
    withRouter,
    connect(mapStateToProps),
  )(WithAuthorization);
}

export default withAuthorization;
```

Here 2 times fat arrow function is done what is exactly return after execution when 2 fat arrow is there. And it's something nested function like or what?? Please any explanation is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What's magic going over here. And other thing is that in outside
>   function argument is given as Component, why is it so!?

You are encountering a higher order component.

There are several resources out there that could be helpful for you. You can looking at higher order components or enhancers in React. They are used interchangeably sometimes.

Do take a look here:

- [React documentation on higher order components](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html)
- [Composing higher order components](https://medium.com/dailyjs/react-composing-higher-order-components-hocs-3a5288e78f55)

Searching in YouTube on the topics is helpful too.

> Here 2 times fat arrow function is done what is exactly return after execution when 2 fat arrow is there. And it's something nested function like or what?? Please any explanation is appreciated.

That's a function returning another function.

Let's take this example:

```
const fn1 = (arg1, arg2) => (arg3, arg4) => {
  return 'Hi' + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4
}
```

This is shorthand for:

```
const fn1 = function (arg1, arg2) {
  return function (arg3, arg4) {
    return 'Hi' + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4
  }
}
```

Also, note that the `=>` binds to your current scope. Do read more [here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881).

The more correct version of the above expanded code is (it's a little harder to read):

```
const fn1 = function (arg1, arg2) {
  return function (arg3, arg4) {
    return 'Hi' + arg1 + arg2 + arg3 + arg4
  }.bind(this)
}.bind(this)
```

That's the difference between the `=>` (fat arrow) and the more traditional `function(){}`. I don't think it's too important to get into differences of the two and you may find investing time on learning about functions returning functions is way more useful in React's context.

Comment: Then why 2 times fat arrow in same line? It will create nested function or something like??

Comment: I realized I missed out that question, I wrote an example within to illustrate how it might look like. I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your help appreciate that!

Comment: No problem. Any time.